# How to exit Fullscreen onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fullscreen mode in my webpage. The image gets fullscreen on clicking a button.
I need to exit the fullscreen by clicking a remove button or by pressing escape button. Which function should I use to achieve this?

### jQuery

```
$('.fullscreen').bind('click', function(event) {
   var sectionId = $(this).parents('ul').attr('id');
   var outputId  sectionId.replace('ul','img');
   var fullObj = $('#singleTemp').clone();
   var imgTarget = $('#' + outputId).attr('src');

   fullObj.find('#full').attr('src', imgTarget);

   $('#fullscreenTemp').html(fullObj.html());

   var target = document.getElementById('fullscreenTemp');
   $('#fullscreenTemp').show();

   screenfull.request(target);
```

I used a jQuery full-screen plugin(screenfull). This is the fullscreen class to the fullscreen button.

HTML

```
  <div id="singleTemp" style="display:none">
     <div id="fullDiv" style="text-align: center">
     <div class="fs-main"> 
     <div class="fs-pic"> <img id="full" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%;" 
         alt="imagecontainer image" src=""/></div>
      <div class="fs-leftarrow"><img  id="1" src="jqe13/image/leftarrow.PNG"/></div>
      <div class="fs-rightarrow"><img src="jqe13/image/rightarrow.PNG"/></div>
      <div class="fs-remove"><img src="jqe13/image/removee.png" height="20" 
    onclick=""/></div>
      <div class="fs-like"> <img src="jqe13/image/like.PNG" height="45"/></div>
      <div class="fs-unlike"><img src="jqe13/image/unlike.PNG" height="45"/></div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

Fullscreen:

```
     <ul>
     <li id="outfullscreen"><a href="#"><img src="jqe13/image/fullscreen_c.PNG" 
        alt="Full Screen" class="fullscreen" title="Full Screen"></a></li></ul>
```

My code is working fine with no errors.Now i want to close the full screen mode with a click.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you'll want the set up an event handler for the [keydown event](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/). After that, you'll have to check for the Esc key (or whatever key you want).

Comment: Esc key is working fine. I just need to close it onclick on remove button .

Comment: @anuRadha can you provide your code or make a fiddle. With this we can only guess and cant give you the opt answer.

Comment: You have some bugs in your code, so what you've posted won't even run.  Please correct them in your question and also post what effect you are seeing (and any errors in your Javascript console).

Comment: Its working fine. i get the fullscreen mode image, and i can even exit the fullscreen by clicking escape. I want to do the same with onclick the remove image in the html i updated in my question.

Comment: @anuRadha Which plugin are you using?

Comment: screenull.js ..its working fine now :) thanx

Comment: @anuRadha Fine, atlast it worked :)  Please share about your fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not mentioned what jQuery plugin you are using. I am assuming you are using `screenfull.js` by looking at your code snippet.

You should be able to exit full screen by calling `screenfull.exit();`

Something like....

```
<button id="exit">Exit</button>
$('#exit').click(function() {
    screenfull.exit();
});
```

Hope this helps.